# How to read grades and remove those below average

Tags: java, arraylist, double

I faced a problem with `ArrayList`. I wrote a simple program which takes the grades and remove the ones below the average! However, it's not working and I couldn't figure where the problem is. I would really appreciate any help. Here is my code

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Double> grades = new ArrayList<Double>();

boolean stop = false;
int i=0;

while(!stop){
    i++;
    System.out.println("Enter the names number "+i+":");
    grades.add(input.nextDouble());

    if(i%5==0){
        System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue ?Enter \"Yes\" or \"No\"");
        stop = (input.next()).equals("No");
    }
}

double sum=0.0;
double ave;
for(int j=0;j<grades.size();j++){
    sum+=grades.get(j);
}
ave = sum/i;

System.out.println("The average of "+(i)+" students is "+ave);
System.out.println("The students grades are: "+grades);

for(int j=0;j<grades.size();j++){//I want to remove any below average grades !?
    if((grades.get(j).doubleValue())<ave){
        System.out.println("\n"+grades.get(j)+"\n");
        grades.remove(j);
    }
    else;
}

System.out.println("\nThe grades that are above the average: "+grades);
```

Comment: Please expand on "it's not working" -- not working how? What input is the program getting? What output are you expecting? What are you seeing? How have you tested and debugged the code?

Comment: The solution is not to remove the values from the array list. Simply print the ones that are greater than the average in the for loop. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you're not adjusting the index when removing, i.e. when calling `grades.remove(j);` you'd need to add a `j--` as well (this is not ideal though, more on that later).

More visual explanation of your problem (you can do something like this on other problems as well):

Assume we have a list `[4, 5, 3, 1, 1, 3, 5, ...]` and an average of `3`.

Now you iterate and at `j = 0` you find 4. You remove that and your list becomes  `[5, 3, 1, 1, 3, 5, ...]`.
Next you check for `j = 1` and see `3`. Did you notice that we skipped `5`? That's because when you remove an element all the others are moved one index down, i.e. the element at index 1 is now at index 0. To accommodate for that you need a `j--` as well, or ...

Alternatively iterate backwards: `for( int j = grades.size() -1; j >= 0; j--)`. This removes the need to adjust the index because your iteration and the elements are both moving in the same direction.

Yet better: use an iterator. That way you can still move from front to back and let the iterator handle the index logic behind the scenes.

```
for( Iterator<Double> itr = grades.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
  Double grade = itr.next();

  //you might want to check for null
  if( grade < ave ){       
    itr.remove();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You remove from the list, but keep increasing the index "j". So each time you remove an element, you will skip the next one.

One easy solution is to iterate backwards:
`for(int j=grades.size() - 1;j >= 0; j--)`